# Nginx not following symlinks

Tags: nginx, symlink

I have installed nginx on Ubuntu 12.04. However, nginx does not seem to follow symlinks. I understand that there is a config change required for this but I am not able to find where to make the change. Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/848526/119666 was interesting to me

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have a look at the following config option from [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks):

> Syntax:
>
> ```
> disable_symlinks off;
> disable_symlinks on |
> if_not_owner [from=part];
> ```
>
> Default:  disable_symlinks off;
>
> Context:  http, server, location
>
> This directive appeared in version 1.1.15.

Comment: O.o very strange. I am on 1.6.1 and am getting an "unknown directive" error with this. I was using it as `location / { disable_symlinks off; }`. Any reason why this happens?

Comment: You need to use this option in your `nginx.conf` configuration, not your website configuration. Edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and place the `disable_symlinks off; ` in the `http` block.

Comment: This is a pretty bad answer, because `off` is already the default.  In other words, by default, all symlinks are already followed; not following symlinks is an extra security feature (that's off by default).

Comment: This is NOT a "pretty bad answer", as it shows and even provides a link to the docs. A default can change from distro to distro, so, assuming the default works in every case is what can be considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 36):

In my case `nginx` was already configured to follow symbolic links. But the issue was the user `nginx` could not access my home files and therefore symbolic link to my home directory was not working.

#### Example

Suppose we have symbolic link `/usr/share/nginx/www/mylink` -> `/home/u/html`

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/www
mkdir   -p  /home/u/html
sudo ln -sv /home/u/html mylink  # creates mylink -> /home/u/html
```

#### Give permissions

Give the **r**ead and e**x**ecute permissions using [`chmod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) and [`find`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)):

```
chmod +rx /home/u
chmod +rw /home/u/html
find /home/u/html/php -type d -exec chmod +rx {} +
find /home/u/html/php -type d -exec chmod +w  {} +  # optional
```

**Notes:**

1. The permission `x` is named e**x**ecute. But when applied to a directory, this permission allows to *recurse the directory tree* (see [Unix modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix))).
2. The command `find ... -exec chmod ...` recursively changes the permissions. We could also use the command `chmod -R +rx /home/myuser/html` but this last command also gives the *execution permission* to all regular files, and we do not want that. The option `-type d` execute `chmod` to only directories.
3. The last optional command gives *write permission* if your PHP scripts require to write data. Try to limit write permission to only required directories for security reasons.

#### Test

No need to restart `ngnix`, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in your browser.

**Caution:** It is not recommended to create symbolic links pointing to your home directory because a mistake on read/write access or a wrong symbolic link may expose your digital data...

**Reference:** [Arch wiki on **nginx**](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx#Error:_403_.28Permission_error.29)

Comment: x is execute iirc, not search

Comment: I had the same problem. As you mentioned the best solution in terms of security is to move the files out of the user directory. A good place it /var/xxx. This solution is working for me and does make things feel more secure.

Answer (score 2):

if olibre's answer doesn't help edit the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and add this line where you've specified your server root directory.

```
autoindex on;
```

save the file and restart server

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Comment: autoindex gives permission to nginx to generate a list of files in a directory

Comment: And source for the claim that this setting that does something different makes symlinks works?