# nginx doesn't follow symlinks with www-data user

Tags: nginx, permissions, ubuntu-14.04, configuration-files, symlink

I have created a folder to the default server at `/var/www/default` and everything works as expected.
Inside that folder I made a symlink to `~/WebstormProjects/my-project`, using the common `ln -s`.
It worked for a while, and the last time I updated using `apt-get`, nginx doesn't follow anymore the symbolic link, which gives me a 404 error, not even listing the symlinks as it used to do.

Tried using the `disable_symlinks` directive, setting it to `off`, and nothing happened. Also followed the steps in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15263923) and still nothing. Also added myself to the `www-data` user, nothing.

But if I edit `nginx.conf` by changing the `user` directive to my own user and restarting the server does work, but I know that's a very bad practice and some day in the future it will not allow PHP-FPM to work.

So, what can I do to make nginx follow symlinks, without changing the owner of my source directories? BTW, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 and nginx 1.4.6 installed via package manager.

Comment: [disable_symlink](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks) has  `if_not_owner` option

Comment: By setting it, I will enable **disabling symlinks**, which is not the behavior I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was just a problem with permissions:

```
chmod 755 /home
chmod 755 /home/user
```

Got previous commands from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688128).